# "Class, interface or enum expected" error in Java

Tags: java, enums

I'm working on this code to build a maze using disjoint set data structure in Java. I'm getting an error("class, interface or enum expected") starting //Building maze using Disjoint Set data structure to end. Can anyone please help me out?

```
//Implementation of Disjoint Set

public class DisjSet {
  private int[] set;
  private int[] sizes;
  private int size;

  public DisjSet(int size) {

       this.set = new int[size];
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { this.set[i] = i; }

       this.sizes = new int[size];
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { this.sizes[i] = 1; }

       this.size = size;
  }

  public int find(int item) {

       int root = item;

       // find the root
       while (set[root] != root) {

             root = set[root];

       }

       // now shorten the paths
       int curr = item;

       while (set[curr] != root) {

             set[curr] = root;

       }

       return root;

  }

  public int join(int item1, int item2) {

       int group1 = find(item1);
       int group2 = find(item2);

       --size;

       if (sizes[group1] > sizes[group2]) {

            set[group2] = group1;

            sizes[group1] += sizes[group2];

            return group1;

       } else {

            set[group1] = group2;

            sizes[group2] += sizes[group1];                

            return group2;

       }

  }

}

//Building maze using Disjoint Set data structure

       Maze createRandomMaze(int rows, int columns) {  
       Maze maze = new Maze(rows, columns);  
       // create all walls  
       List<Wall> walls = maze.getAllInnerWalls();  
       // remove all the walls you can  
       DisjSet diset = new DisjSet(rows*columns);  
       while (diset.size() > 1) {  
            int wallIndex = random.nextInt(walls.size());  
            int cell1 = walls.get(wallIndex).cell1;  
            int cell2 = walls.get(wallIndex).cell2;  
            if (diset.find(cell1) != diset.find(cell2)) {  
                 // we can remove the wall  
                 maze.removeWall(walls.get(wallIndex));  
                 diset.join(cell1, cell2);  
            }  
            walls.remove(wallIndex);  
       }  
       return maze;  
}
```

Comment: Your `createRandomMaze` method is after your `DisjSet` class, it should probably be inside the class .

Answer (score 0):

These:

```
   Maze createRandomMaze(int rows, int columns) {  
   Maze maze = new Maze(rows, columns);  
   // create all walls  
   List<Wall> walls = maze.getAllInnerWalls();  
   // remove all the walls you can  
   DisjSet diset = new DisjSet(rows*columns);  
   while (diset.size() > 1) {  
        int wallIndex = random.nextInt(walls.size());  
        int cell1 = walls.get(wallIndex).cell1;  
        int cell2 = walls.get(wallIndex).cell2;  
        if (diset.find(cell1) != diset.find(cell2)) {  
             // we can remove the wall  
             maze.removeWall(walls.get(wallIndex));  
             diset.join(cell1, cell2);  
        }  
        walls.remove(wallIndex);  
   }  
   return maze;
```

should be put inside a method, only declarations are allowed at class level.

If you have a `main` method, already, move the above code there. If you don't, declare a `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // put the above code here...
}
```

Now when you run your code, the `main` method will be called and the above lines will be run.